# Using wget to download SSRS Results

Tags: reporting-services, wget

Is it possible to use wget to download a csv of an SSRS package with the URL?

I have tried http auth and user/pass auth with no success

For example the url I am trying to access looks something like this:

> http://foobar/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=5&ControlID=7&FileName=blah&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=CSV

And when I paste the URL into a browser it downloads without a problem but when I attempt to access it via wget I get the error message *"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Server Error"* or a *"401 Unauthorized"*.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Brad